# Best Way to Inventory the Media Library of a 200+ Multisite Installation?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, theme-development, development-strategy, switch-to-blog

I have a multisite installation of WordPress with 200+ sites. I recently was tasked to do an inventory of each site's media library and was wondering if this could be accomplished programmatically with a script? If so, what would be the most efficient way to query each site's media library?

Comment: I've tried using wp_get_sites() and then looping through them using the switch_to_blog() function but I've read that the switch_to_blog() function is resource intensive, which is something I have to be mindful of since it's the production server.. I'm assuming I can accomplish the same results using a custom query?

Comment: so what, you not going to run this more then once in a blue moon, no?

Comment: Yeah, that's true.

Comment: You could also backup the wp-content and database from production to a staging or dev system if you're worried about the load and run the inventory job on copy without loading the production system.

Comment: Great idea, thanks for the suggestion - it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check this: [How do I query all posts of one type across my multisite installation?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28081/how-do-i-query-all-posts-of-one-type-across-my-multisite-installation?rq=1)

Just change post to media and you'll be fine.